# How to check if string matches date pattern using time API?

Tags: java, java-8, datetime-format, datetime-parsing, java-time

My program is parsing an input string to a [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) object. For most of the time the string looks like `30.03.2014`, but occasionally it looks like `3/30/2014`. Depending on which, I need to use a different pattern to call `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(String pattern)` with. Basically, I need to check if the string matches the pattern `dd.MM.yyyy` or `M/dd/yyyy` before doing the parsing.

The regex approach would be something like:

```
LocalDate date;
if (dateString.matches("^\\d?\\d/\\d{2}/\\d{4}$")) {
  date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/dd/yyyy"));  
} else {
  date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"));  
}
```

This works, but it would be nice to use the date pattern string when matching the string also.

Are there any standard ways to do this with the new Java 8 time API, without resorting to regex matching? I have looked in the docs for [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Why dont you string `replace("//", ".")` ?

Comment: I don't think there is a specific method to check if a date follows a given pattern. I would use the SimpleDateFormat.parse method and check for a ParseException. In case you are sure that the date is correct and it is in one of the two patterns, you could just check if there is '.' in the string.

Comment: @RobertNiestroj Because month and day are not positioned the same place in both patterns.

Comment: @HermanTorjussen I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't know if it will be a viable option for you to create a class for this. Is it? Like this: http://www.tryjava8.com/app/snippets/5368a343e4b0753f2af0f806

Comment: @Max The class `SimpleDateFormat` cannot directly parse to a `LocalDate`, only to `java.util.Date` which is quite different.

Comment: @ZouZou That's a possible solution, if no other solutions exists already. Please do post it as an answer anyway. BTW, that site you linked failed when I ran the example.

Comment: @HermanTorjussen Look at my updated answer, it may be simple than creating a class for that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Okay I'm going ahead and posting it as an answer. One way is to create the class that will holds the patterns.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyFormatter format = new MyFormatter("dd.MM.yyyy", "M/dd/yyyy");
        LocalDate  date = format.parse("3/30/2014"); //2014-03-30
        LocalDate  date2 = format.parse("30.03.2014"); //2014-03-30
    }
}

class MyFormatter {
    private final String[] patterns;

    public MyFormatter(String... patterns){
        this.patterns = patterns;
    }

    public LocalDate parse(String text){
        for(int i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++){
            try{
                return LocalDate.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(patterns[i]));
            }catch(DateTimeParseException excep){}
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not able to parse the date for all patterns given");
    }
}
```

You could improve this as @MenoHochschild did by directly creating an array of `DateTimeFormatter` from the array of `String` you pass in the constructor.

---

Another way would be to use a [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html), appending the formats you want. There may exists some other ways to do it, I didn't go deeply through the documentation :-)

```
DateTimeFormatter dfs = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                           .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))                                                                 
                           .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"))                                                                                     
                           .toFormatter();
LocalDate d = LocalDate.parse("2014-05-14", dfs); //2014-05-14
LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.parse("14.05.2014", dfs); //2014-05-14
```

Comment: Your second Options works brilliant, without handling Exception etc.

Answer (score 1):

With [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), optional patterns can be specified using square brackets.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[d.M.u][M/d/u][u-M-d]", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Stream.of(
                    "3/30/2014",
                    "30.03.2014",
                    "2014-05-14",
                    "14.05.2014"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(s, dtf)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-03-30
2014-03-30
2014-05-14
2014-05-14
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The approach of @ZouZou is a possible solution.

In order to avoid using exceptions for program logic as much as possible (also not so nice performancewise) following [alternative](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseUnresolved-java.lang.CharSequence-java.text.ParsePosition-) might be considered:

```
static final String[] PATTERNS = {"dd.MM.yyyy", "M/dd/yyyy"};
static final DateTimeFormatter[] FORMATTERS = new DateTimeFormatter[PATTERNS.length];

static {
  for (int i = 0; i < PATTERNS.length; i++) {
    FORMATTERS[i] = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(PATTERNS[i]);
  }
}

public static LocalDate parse(String input) {
  ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition();
  for (int i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++) {
    try {
      TemporalAccessor tacc = FORMATTERS[i].parseUnresolved(input, pos);
      if (pos.getErrorIndex < 0) {
        return LocalDate.from(tacc); // possibly throwing DateTimeException => validation failure
      }
    } catch (DateTimeException ex) { // catches also possible DateTimeParseException
      // go to next pattern
    }
    pos.setIndex(0);
    pos.setErrorIndex(-1);
  }
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input does not match any pattern: " + input);
}
```

**More explanation about the method `parseUnresolved()`:**

This method does only the first phase of parsing, so there is no second phase containing preliminary validation or combining effort of parsed fields. However, `LocalDate.from()` does validate every input, so I think this is still sufficient. And the advantage is that `parseUnresolved()` uses the error index of `ParsePosition`. This is in agreement with traditional `java.text.Format`-behaviour.

Unfortunately the alternative and more intuitive method [DateTimeFormater.parse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.text.ParsePosition-) first creates a `DateTimeParseException` and then store the error index in this exception. So I decided not to use this method in order to avoid the creation of an unnecessary exception. For me, this API-detail is a questionable design decision.